# Java Generics - are these two method declarations equivalent?

Tags: java, generics

Given some class `SomeBaseClass`. Are these two method declarations equivalent?

```
public <T extends SomeBaseClass> void myMethod(T param)
```

and

```
public void myMethod(<? extends SomeBaseClass> param)
```

Comment: -1 for not even trying to compile it.

Comment: I don't think you can do that second thing there.  Might want to wrap it with `List` or something (ex: `List<? extends SomeBaseClass>`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, these are not equivalent. The second won't even compile as it has no meaning (why would you use generics in that case anyway?)

Comment: public <T extends Record> void retrieve(String key, Class<T> clz) 
 
public void myMethod(Class<? extends Record> param)
  
 }

Comment: Correct question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730929/java-generics-are-these-two-method-declarations-equivalent-correct-version)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, `? extends SomeBaseClass` is not a type and doesn't make sense there. However, you can really just put `SomeBaseClass` there, because anything that is an instance of a subclass of `SomeBaseClass` is, by inheritance, also an instance of `SomeBaseClass`.

So, from the perspective of someone calling these functions, (since `T` is only used once, and therefore has no constraining effect on other types), the following two are functionally equivalent:

```
public <T extends SomeBaseClass> void myMethod(T param)
```

and

```
public void myMethod(SomeBaseClass param)
```

Note, however, that these two will appear differently to reflection. Also, there might be some need inside the function for a generic type `T`, so the first form may be necessary in some cases (although one can still write a wrapper for it in the second form in this case).