# Is ? super/extends byte[] makes sense?

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I just wrote following method.

```java
static <R> R encodeBase16(final Supplier<? extends byte[]> supplier,
                          final Function<? super byte[], ? extends R> function) {
    requireNonNull(supplier, "supplier is null");
    requireNonNull(function, "function is null");
    return function.apply(encodeBase16(supplier.get()));
}
```

While the compiler seems have no problems with it.

Are those `? extends byte[]` and `? super byte[]` parts makes sense? Or can I just use `byte[]`?

```java
static <R> R encodeBase16(final Supplier<byte[]> supplier,
                          final Function<byte[], ? extends R> function) {
    requireNonNull(supplier, "supplier is null");
    requireNonNull(function, "function is null");
    return function.apply(encodeBase16(supplier.get()));
}
```

Comment: Nothing can be added to @sweeper's answer. Anyway If I were you I would keep wildcards in your code because it honors PECS principle and hence it has also documentation purpose. Once somebody can refactor `byte[]` to `SomeCustomClass` and then wildcards would be kind of necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fine. You can put any reference type after `extends`/`super` in a wildcard bound. See the production rule [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1):

```
TypeArguments:
  < TypeArgumentList >
TypeArgumentList:
  TypeArgument {, TypeArgument}
TypeArgument:
  ReferenceType 
  Wildcard
Wildcard:
  {Annotation} ? [WildcardBounds]
WildcardBounds:
  extends ReferenceType 
  super ReferenceType
```

As you know, using wildcards allows the possibility of subtypes of `byte[]` to be used as the type argument for an `extends byte[]` wildcard, and supertypes of `byte[]` to be used as the type argument for an `super byte[]` wildcard. As far as I know, there are no subtypes of `byte[]` and the only super types of `byte[]` are:

- `Object`
- `Serializable`
- `Cloneable`

according to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.3). So for example you could pass a `Function<Object, R>` to that method:

```
Function<Object, String> function = x -> null;
encodeBase16(() -> null, function);
```

Is this *useful*? I wouldn't say so, but you are allowed to do non-useful things.

[Related question about "redundant" use of wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607274/java-thencomparing-wildcard-signature)