# Java - Definition of the comparing method of Comparator class

Tags: java, generics, methods, lambda, comparator

I would like to understand the definition of the method `comparing` of Comparator class. I will leave some code in case it helps with the explanation. I'm working with a class called Person that basically stores a name and a last name. This data can be retrieve with get methods.

```
public class Person {

    private final String name;
    private final String lastname;

    public Person(String name, String lastname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    //...
}
```

I then created a list of Persons:

```java
List<Person> list = Arrays.asList(
    new Person("Juan", "García"),
    new Person("Ana", "Martínez"),
    ...
);
```

I've been testing different ways to sort this list of Persons. Among other possibilities, I found this one:

```java
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getName));
```

I understand what these lines do. Basically, this list is sorted using a Comparator that compares using a sort key (a Person's name). Such key is extracted using a reference to the getName method belonging to the Person class.

However, I also like to understand what's going on behind the scenes. My problem is with the `comparing` method. The Java documentation defines such method like this:

```java
static <T,U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U> keyExtractor)
```

Particularly, I'm struggling with the generic types definition: `<T,U extends Comparable<? super U>>`; and the definition of the parameter's type: `Function<? super T,? extends U>`

`T` represents the comparator type, while `U` represents the key type, right?  So... Why `U` needs to extends `Comparable<? super U>`, which in turns uses any superclass of `U`?

In the argument, the function works with an object belonging to any superclass of `T` and returns an object belonging to any subclass of `U` (`<? super T,? extends U>`), but... why though?

I hope my doubt is clear. Also, sorry for the long explanation.

Comment: What do _you_ think the method's signature should look like? Knowing that will probably make it clear to me where your confusion is.

Comment: @Sweeper I'm not really good with generics, still learning. Anyway, my logic dictates something like this:

static <? super T, U> Comparator<T> comparing(Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor)

It's returning a Comparator of type T, but it could also be a subclass, right? However, I think I kind of understand the function (Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor) definition though. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three main confusions here:

#### Why `U extends Comparable<? super U>`?

This is a constraint on `U` (the key's type), specifying what specific types `U` can be. It says that `U` must be comparable. Makes sense, right? The part in the angle brackets specifies "what things can `U` be compared to?" For example, `Comparable<Animal>` means "comparable to animals". The constraint says "`U` must be comparable to some supertype of `U`".

You might be wondering why doesn't it just say "`U` must be comparable to `U`", i.e. `U extends Comparable<U>`. This is because we are trying to make our method as flexible as possible, i.e. we try to accept as many different `U`s as possible. If I have a `Dog` that can be compared to an `Animal` (implements `Comparable<Animal>`), it makes logical sense that the dog can also be compared to another `Dog`. However, since `Dog` implements `Comparable<Animal>` rather than `Comparable<Dog>`, it doesn't satisfy `U extends Comparable<U>`, which is why we have to use `U extends Comparable<? extends U>`.

#### Why does the `Function` take `? super T`?

Imagine I have a key extractor that takes an `Object`, and I return its `toString()` output as the key to compare (this is a very uncommon thing to compare, but for the sake of this example, bear with me :D)

```
Function<Object, String> stringExtractor = Object::toString;
```

Now I want a comparator that compares animals. Can I use this `stringExtractor` as the argument for `comparing`? Of course I can:

```
Comparator<Animal> comparator = Comparator.comparing(stringExtractor);
```

All animals have a `toString` method, as they are subclasses of `Object` after all! This is why the key extractor parameter takes functions that take a superclass of `T` - to allow us to pass things like the above. If it were `Function<T, ? extends U>`, we wouldn't be able to do `Comparator.comparing(stringExtractor)`.

Again, the idea is that we want `comparing` to work with as many things as possible.

#### Why does the `Function` return `? extends U`?

This is actually quite unnecessary. Unless you explicitly specify `T` and `U` like this:

```
Comparator.<Foo, Animal>comparing(Foo::getDog);
```

It makes no difference whether it is `Function<? super T, U>` or `Function<? super T, ? extends U>`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607274/java-thencomparing-wildcard-signature) for more details. That question is about `thenComparing`, which has the signature as `comparing`.

Comment: Thank you. Just a couple of doubts:
1. Using the classes Dog and Animal, `U extends Comparable<? super U>`, would be "translated" like: `Dog extends Comparable<any_super_class_of_Dog>`. But shouldn't it say `U implements Comparable<? super U>`?
2. "If I have a Dog that can be compared to an Animal (`implements Comparable<Animal>`)... ", this would mean that a dog could be compare to a cat or a cow if we directly call the compareTo() method from the dog instance, but it won't work when using the comparing method of Comparator, unless Dog `implements Comparable<? super Dog>`, right?

Comment: @DamianGDO 1. You always use `extends` when specifying a generic constraint. Don’t think of it in the sense of “inheritance”. 2. Yes, you understand correctly. It won’t work unless you have the constraint `U extends Comparable<? super U>`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider the signature of the mentioned method `comparing`
`static <T,U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U> keyExtractor)`

- `T` is the type of object being compared, in the mentioned case it is `Person`
- `U extends <Comparable<? super U>>` describes the type used to implement actual comparison - that's why this type must be `Comparable` - in this case it is `String`
- `Function<? super T,? extends U> keyExtractor` - `keyExtractor` is a function which "converts" objects of class `T` (`Person`) to comparable objects of class `U` (`String`) - in this class it is a getter of name defined in class `Person`.