# Generics in Java does not compile

Tags: java, generics

I am stuck trying to understand what exactly is going on over here. The two ways that the copy_v1 method is being used are shown below. The first way (1) produces a compile error. But the second way (2) does not produce any compile error (nor does it produce any runtime error when I try to execute the program once I comment out (1)). When I replace (2) with `copy_v1(new Wrapper<String>("Hello"), new Wrapper<Object>(new Object()));`, I end up getting a compile error on (2) as well. Not sure what is happening. How is the code on (1) any different from (2)? Can someone shed some light on this please.

Thanks.

```
public class SOQuestion {

    public static <T> void copy_v1(Wrapper<T> source, Wrapper<T> dest) {
        T srcObj = source.getRef();
        dest.setRef(srcObj);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Wrapper<Object> objectWrapper = new Wrapper<>(new Object());
        Wrapper<String> stringWrapper = new Wrapper<>("Hello");
        copy_v1(stringWrapper, objectWrapper); // Compile error on this line (1)
        copy_v1(new Wrapper<>("Hello"), new Wrapper<>(new Object())); // But no error on this line (2)
    }

}

class Wrapper<T> {

    private T ref;

    Wrapper(T ref) {this.ref = ref;}

    public T getRef() {return this.ref;}

    public void setRef(T ref) {this.ref = ref;}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `copy_v1(stringWrapper, objectWrapper);`, the generic parameter `T` for `copy_v1` cannot be inferred. There is actually no valid type for `T`, such that the call is valid.

If `T` is `String`, then the second argument cannot be converted to `Wrapper<String>`. `Wrapper<Object>` is not a kind of `Wrapper<String>`, because you can call `setRef(new Object())` on the former, but not on the latter. I know that you are not doing that in `copy_v1`, but the compiler doesn't look at what happens in the method to determine whether a call is valid.

Similarly, if `T` is `Object`, then the first argument cannot be converted to `Wrapper<Object>`. `Wrapper<String>` is not a kind of `Wrapper<Object>`. You are guaranteed to get a `String` when you call `getRef` on the former, but not on the latter.

However, in `copy_v1(new Wrapper<>("Hello"), new Wrapper<>(new Object()));`, you are asking the compiler to infer the type arguments for the `Wrapper`s too. In that case, the compiler would try its best to make your method call valid, and infer it like this:

```
SOQuestion.<Object>copy_v1(new Wrapper<Object>("Hello"), new Wrapper<Object>(new Object()));
```

`T` for `copy_v1` is `Object`, and the `T`s for both `Wrapper`s are `Object`. Now everything is valid. `new Wrapper<Object>` accepts an `Object` parameter, and `"Hello"` can be passed to that, because `String` inherits from `Object`.

Note that if you change your `copy_v1` to this:

```
public static <T> void copy_v1(Wrapper<? extends T> source, Wrapper<? super T> dest) {
    T srcObj = source.getRef();
    dest.setRef(srcObj);
}
```

Then doing `copy_v1(stringWrapper, objectWrapper);` is fine. This limits what you can do with `dest` and `source` inside the method, but allowing callers to pass e.g. `Wrapper<String>` to `dest` when it's supposed to take a `Wrapper<Object>`.

Comment: You need only one of `? extends` and `? super`. Having both is kind of redundant. I would remove `? extends`, but either way works.

Comment: @Andreas It does matter if you specify the generic parameters explicitly. But my reason for doing that is because of my own convention - using `extends` on all producers and `super` on all consumers. [The JDK does this too.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607274/java-thencomparing-wildcard-signature)

Answer (score 2):

When using `new Wrapper<String>("Hello")` as an argument to `copy_v1`, the inferred type is `Wrapper<Object>`, whereas with your first example, the type of `objectWrapper` is `Wrapper<String>`.

Essentially:

```
copy_v1(new Wrapper<>("Hello"), new Wrapper<>(new Object()));
```

is equivalent to:

```
Wrapper<Object> objectWrapper = new Wrapper<>(new Object());
Wrapper<Object> stringWrapper = new Wrapper<>("Hello");
copy_v1(stringWrapper, objectWrapper);
```

which isn't quite what you have in your first case.

Comment: Thank you. One follow-up question: why is the type of ```new Wrapper<String>("Hello")``` when being passed in as a direct args to the copy_v1 function being inferred as ```Wrapper<Object>``` when I can see that I can successfully assign it to a reference of type ```Wrapper<String>``` (as being done on Line 2 of ```main```)

Comment: @rgbk21 I'm not sure what you mean. `new Wrapper<String>("Hello")` is never inferred to be of type `Wrapper<Object>`. Do you mean `new Wrapper<>("Hello")`?

Comment: Yes I'm not quite sure where you're referring to, you don't have `new Wrapper<String>(...)` anywhere in your example.

Comment: I am sorry. I pasted the wrong code snippet by mistake. But I think Sweeper mentioned how the types are being inferred. My question was that - on line 2 of ```main``` we are able to reference ```new Wrapper<>("Hello")``` by using ```Wrapper<String>```. Then how is the compiler inferring the same instantiation of ```new Wrapper<>("Hello")``` as of type ```Wrapper<Object>``` on line 4.

Comment: I don't have a source for how the inference works exactly here, but I would expect that the inference engine would infer the types that would match your method call. The (better) answer from @Sweeper also says something similar: *"In that case, the compiler would try its best to make your method call valid, and infer it like this: [...]".*